# ¿Cómo hacer una búsqueda estricta con la función "str_replace"?

Tags: php, funciones

Utilizando la función de php, str_replace, trato de convertir nombres propios, primeramente en tipo Capital, para posterior sustituir las conexiones de los nombres compuestos, algo así como: "De Los Santos" a "de los Santos", con una función:

```
  function nombres_compuestos($var)
{
    $var =  mb_convert_encoding(mb_convert_case($var, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
    $conexiones = array("Del", "Los", "El", "La", "De", "Y");
    $sustituto = array("del", "los", "el", "la", "de", "y");
    $nombrebien = str_replace($conexiones, $sustituto, $var);

    return $nombrebien;
}
```

El problema es que con nombres como Delina o Elena, me convierte las primeras letras en minúsculas, ¿hay algún símbolo para hacerlo estricto?

Comment: Podrias agregar un espacio al final de cada palabra

Comment: simple, pero inquebrantable